# how to remove the borders in JQuery Layout?

Tags: javascript, jquery, layout

Hello I am using jquery layout plugin from http://layout.jquery-dev.net/ .
my options are following:

```
 <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 // create page layout
 pageLayout = $('body').layout(
   {applyDemoStyles:   true,
    spacing_open:0,
    spacing_closed: 0,
    slidable:  false,
    togglerLength_closed:  0

    });
 pageLayout.panes.north.css('backgroundColor','#A6f');

 // we need to remove the borders as well....

});
</script>
```

This removes sliders but:
How to remove the pane borders as well?

thanks Arman.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Remove one border:**

```
pageLayout.panes.north.css('border','none');
```

**Remove all borders:**

As you should be quite sure that each `pageLayout.pane` will have `o` as a property:

```
for(property in pageLayout.panes){
     pageLayout.panes[property].css('border', 'none');
}
```

How you should really do it - checks to make sure `o` is a property of `pageLayout.pane` before attempting to access it:

```
for(property in pageLayout.panes){
     if(pageLayout.panes.hasOwnProperty(property)){
          pageLayout.panes[property].css('border', 'none');
     }
}
```

Comment: thanks!!! and what about removing for all? should I write css('border','none'); for each pane?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this plugin yet but since your last line is pretty much like the usual css try this.

```
pageLayout.panes.north.css({'backgroundColor' : '#A6f', 'border' : 'none'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a css rewriting. After including the css layout file in the head section (usually jquery.ui.layout.css) you could add a style that rewrites the original.

```
<style>
    .ui-layout-pane { 
            background: #FFF;
            border: 0 none; //This rewrites the original style
            padding: 10px;
            overflow: auto;
        }
</style>
```